# Output redirection in C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to redirect output in C (`./a.out > out.log`), I want printf to print to the file instead of stdout, for some reason I couldn't achieve that, I also can't understand what 'copy' means in `dup2` description in the linux manual:

> **dup2()** makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if
>   necessary

Is copy means redirect?

Thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
  FILE *fout=fopen("out.log","wt");
  if(!fout)
    return 1;

  printf("Hi stdout\n");

  if(dup2(fileno(fout),fileno(stdout) == -1)) return 1;

  printf("Hi file\n");

  fclose(fout);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [newer version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) of the man page is more informative. It actually means a **copy** of the file descriptor, so the system call can indeed be used to implement redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a means of redirection. Your code would work otherwise, except for the typo:

You're dupping to fd numbered `fileno(stdout) == -1`; since `stdout` is initially opened to file descriptor `1`, the comparison is `1 == -1` which is false; i.e. `0` and you end up dup2ing your new file descriptor over *standard input* instead of standard output.

Obviously the code should have been:

```
// notice the parentheses here      v
if (dup2(fileno(fout),fileno(stdout)) == -1) return 1;
```

Addendum, you probably would want to `fflush` the stdout before dupping, just to be sure - because the stdout might not be line buffered.

It is more portable to use the [`freopen`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.4) to reopen `stdout`, but this will redirect only output from stdio functions, not the output from unix system calls or subprocesses.

Comment: Haha, nice one. Thanks.